# Changing date format and storing it in a variable in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;
public class sql_type4 
{
    public static void main(String args[]){  
    Date fun;
    Date fun2;
        try{  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mca2b","root","siddheshkk");  
     Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  


    ResultSet result=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id,name, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateee),'%d/%m/%Y') as datee from  empwhere dateee >= curdate()"); 
    while(result.next())
    {
        fun=result.getDate("datee");
        System.out.println(fun);
    }
    con.close();  
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { 
        System.out.println(e);
    }  
    }  
    }
```

Here i just want to change the format of date and store the result in one variable .  So how can i do it ?
Above code gives error bad format for date  '22/08/1970' in column 3.
Anybody please help.  Thanks alot in advance :)

Comment: **empwhere**? It should be **emp where**. Put a space before where clause.

Comment: actually that was not the issue it was my mistake while posting code here .anyways thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use the [JDBC GetDate() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(java.lang.String)) to retrieve a text string.  That's because you converted a standard MySQL date data type to a string in your query with DATE_FORMAT(). The resulting value doesn't look like a date, so JDBC gacks on it. You probably should use [GetString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)) instead. Or, maybe you should do the conversion to your desired date format in your Java code rather than in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks alot Sir . It worked and cleared my concept too :)